# Rust container run from docker-compose makes Docker irresponsive

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, rust-cargo

I have a Docker container for my Rust application which:

```
FROM rust:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN curl -L --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cargo-bins/cargo-binstall/main/install-from-binstall-release.sh | bash
RUN echo "yes" | cargo binstall cargo-watch
RUN echo "yes" |  cargo binstall sqlx-cli
CMD ["cargo", "watch", "-x", "run"]
```

When I build and run "x-zeus" image as is, it works file:

```
* docker build -t x-zeus . 
* docker run -p 3001:3001 x-zeus:latest
```

Then calling `http://0.0.0.0:3001/v1/ping` will return `200`

Doing the same via `docker-compose` causes Docker to become **unresponsive**.

```
zeus:
    build:
      context: zeus
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./zeus:/app
    env_file: .env
```

Why does Docker hang when the Rust image is run from docker-compose? One time I managed to attach logs before it died, I saw that `cargo run` was running and dependencies were being installed.

Note, I'm using `colima`

#### Cache

What volumes do I need to mount to speed up rebuilt time in Docker container?

Comment: In the Compose case, you're overwriting the image's content with `volumes:`.  Does deleting that block help?

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes, thanks, removing `volume` made it work. But cargo-watch doesn't work, as I change code in the src, it doesn't rebuild. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to remove `COPY . .` and added `volume`, now it stuck again while compiling dependencies.